# laravel polymorphic relationships on both sides

Tags: database, laravel, polymorphism, relationship, polymorphic-associations

I have 2 models (Agency and Client) and two location types: State and City. I want to make possible to set a location (any of the states OR cities) to agencies and clients.

```
┌──────────────┐  ┌──────────────┐    ┌───────────┐  ┌───────────┐
│ agencies     │  │ clients      │    │ states    │  │ cities    │
├──────────────┤  ├──────────────┤    ├───────────┤  ├───────────┤
│ id           │  │ id           │    │ id        │  │ id        │
│ name         │  │ ...          │    │ name      │  │ name      │
│ location...  │  │ location...  │    │ acronym   │  │ state_id  │
└──────────────┘  └──────────────┘    └───────────┘  └───────────┘
```

I thought about making polymorphism from agencies and clients (both tables would have the columns `location_id` and `location_type`) and it works, but I want to know if there is any other smarter and cleaner way to do this (remembering that cities belong to states, so I should be able to do `$model->location->state` if the chosen location for the `$model` is a city).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is. The best way to do this would be to have a `location` table that would have these fields:

```
+-------------+-------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| type        | enum('city','state')    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| parent_type | enum('agency','client') | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| id          | int(11)                 | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| parent_id   | int(11)                 | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

You would then insert your records in this table to associate them.

Your `$model->location->state` would then grab the `city` or `state` depending on the `parent_type` and `parent_id`.